# Remove Duplication From The Validate Method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What is a good way to remove the duplication in the validate method?

```
public bool Validate()
{  
    string directoryErrorMessage = "Directory does not exist";

    if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.InPath)) _settingsView.SetInPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
    if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.OutPath)) _settingsView.SetOutPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
    if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.ProcessedPath)) _settingsView.SetProcessedPathError(directoryErrorMessage);

    return CheckPathExists(_settingsView.InPath) && 
        CheckPathExists(_settingsView.OutPath) &&
        CheckPathExists(_settingsView.ProcessedPath);
}

private bool CheckPathExists(string path)
{
    return Directory.Exists(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling CheckPathExists() two times for each path, try calling it only once, save the result in a boolean and then use the boolean variable value.

Comment: The multiple calls to CheckPathExists doesn't really bug me as much as getting rid of the multiple if statements. The only thing that changes in them is the path string Ex: (CheckPathExists(_settingsView.xxxxxx) and the error message method SetxxxxError. I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Store each check in a variable, that way you only check once and then reuse the variable.

```
public bool Validate()
{  
    const string directoryErrorMessage = "Directory does not exist";
    bool inPathExists = CheckPathExists(_settingsView.InPath);
    bool outPathExists = CheckPathExists(_settingsView.OutPath);
    bool processedPathExists = CheckPathExists(_settingsView.ProcessedPath);

    if(!inPathExists) _settingsView.SetInPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
    if(!outPathExists) _settingsView.SetOutPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
    if(!processedPathExists) _settingsView.SetProcessedPathError(directoryErrorMessage);

    return inPathExists && 
        outPathExists &&
        processedPathExists;
}
```

I don't know if you have control on the `_settingsView` class or not, but it may be better to let it handle the validation itself. It could probably validate when the path's are set and set the appropriate error message at that time. Then in your validate code it would only have to check the IsValid property of the _settingsView object.

```
//to use the below class, your Validate method would change to
public bool Validate()
{
    return _settingsView.IsValid;
}

internal class SettingsView
{
    private const string DirectoryErrorMessage = "Directory does not exist";

    private string _inPath;
    private string _inPathError;
    private bool _inPathValid;

    private string _outPath;
    private string _outPathError;
    private bool _outPathValid;

    private string _processedPath;
    private string _processedPathError;
    private bool _processedPathValid;

    public string InPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _inPath;
        }
        set
        {
            _inPath = value;
            _inPathValid = Directory.Exists(_inPath);
            _inPathError = _inPathValid ? string.Empty : DirectoryErrorMessage;
        }
    }
    public string InPathError
    {
        get
        {
            return _inPathError ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    // Write similar code for Out and Processed paths
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return _inPathValid && _outPathValid && _processedPathValid;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 method in class:

```
public bool Validate()
{  
   return  CheckInPath() &CheckOutPath()&CheckProcessedPath();
}

  public bool CheckInPath()
  {
       if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.InPath)) {
            _settingsView.SetInPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

     public bool CheckOutPath(string path)
     {
         if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.InPath)) {
               _settingsView.SetOutPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
               return false;
          }
          return true;
     }

      public bool CheckProcessedPath(string path)
      {
          if(!CheckPathExists(_settingsView.ProcessedPath)) {
              _settingsView.SetProcessedPathError(directoryErrorMessage);
               return false;
            }
            return true;
       }
```